# asp .net mvc4 encrypt/decrypt(bcrypt), LINQ edit data in list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, bcrypt

Actually I am working on an Ebank, to learn more about MVC and OOP.

A person can **register**, and can **create** more than one **bankaccount** for himself. When he posts the data the controller calls a thread-safe random generator that makes 3x8  0-9 numbers then parses it to string. After this I could **encrypt** the **numbers** with Bcrypt, then upload it to db.

**What I want to achieve:**
     If I list out of his existing bankaccounts he shouldnt be able to see all the numbers, only the last 4!
*Like*: **xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxx1234**

**Controller:**

```
var bankaccounts = db.BankAccounts.Include(b => b.UserProfile).Where(b => b.UserId == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId).ToList();
```

**1**,  Should I decrypt the bankaccounts.AccountNumber, then delete all of the characters except for the last 4 characters?

- a,I cannot access the bankaccounts.AccountNumber row, neither change
  it. How can I ?
- b,How safe is this? I am quite sure this is not the best way to
  do!

> ```
> foreach(var element in bankaccounts.AccountNumber)
> {
> string tempstring = bankaccounts.AccountNumber.element.Bcrypt.Decrypt;
> tempstring = tempstring.getlast4character;
> bankaccounts.AccountNumber.element = tempstring;
> }
> return bankaccounts to the view</li>
> ```
>
> **2**, To achieve my Goal, I think this is not a Safe way to do. Could you give me **some advices**, if I am wrong or right, and **suggest me some detailed new ways** to accomplish my task?

Comment: Right before you encrypt the numbers using Bcrypt and upload them to the DB, you should also create a string of just the last four numbers and store it un-encrypted somewhere accessible.

Going through the trouble of retrieving the full number, decrypting and cutting the string is silly.